# Adding seconds to javascript DateTime object through the use of a prompt

Tags: javascript

I have this webpage that takes in an input in seconds, and produces what the time will be after the time has elapsed. So I went about it using the following code

```js
let duration = prompt("Enter your trip duration in seconds: ");  // get the time from the vaue of the input element

let newtime = new Date(); // get the current time
newtime.setSeconds(newtime.getSeconds() + duration)
```

I decided to test the code and it gave me weird results and for some reason when I divided the duration by ten it started to work. Even though it worked I wasn't satisfied. So I added some more code to try and find where the bug is.

```js
let oldtime = new Date();
oldtime.setSeconds(oldtime.getSeconds() + 60);
```

I added some code so that it would show on the webpage to compare the two times and these are my results when I enter 60 as the duration...

[image: Code]

Just a little summary. The code works when I hard code the values in but it behaves weirdly if I try get the input from a prompt

Answer (score 3):

You are concatenating a string to a number instead of adding. You have to parse the result from `prompt` to a number (with the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) operator):

```js
let duration = prompt("Enter your trip duration in seconds: "); // get the time from the vaue of the input element

let newtime = new Date(); // get the current time
newtime.setSeconds(newtime.getSeconds() + +duration)
console.log(newtime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because you need to parse the duration from a string to  number. So, try this

`newtime.setSeconds(newtime.getSeconds() + parseInt(duration, 10))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon) to deal with dates and times without having to worry about unexpected behaviour like the one you described.

```
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

const now = DateTime.now();
const timeAfterTrip.plus({ seconds: duration });

console.log(timeAfterTrip);
```